# Jenkins Blueocean - same Jenkinsfile across multiple environments while passing different values of environment variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I do not want to put my environment variables in the source code, i know we can add variables in Jenkinsfile.

How can i pass environment variable via the Jenkins job/UI while using Jenkins Blueocean?

This needs to be done in a way so that I can use same Jenkinsfile across multiple environments while passing different values of environment variables.

Comment: why not?  What is wrong with having something like in Jenkinsfile
environment {
     MAVEN_OPTS = "-Xmx2024m"
     JAVA_OPTS = "-Xmx2024m"
     DOCKERTAG = "v1.8.0"
     dockerhub = credentials('dockerhub.credentials')
 }
Are the going to change? Would you rather have them as parameters to be passed in at runtime?

Comment: I can put these kind of ENV variables in Jenkinsfile but what if it's a secret token or a license key? I would not like to checkin those secrets into my source code. Yes, i do want to change parameters runtime.

Comment: you can use the credentials plugin.  I am using dockerhub = credentials('dockerhub.credentials') , for my dockerhub credentials,  the secrets are not checked into code, but managed via jenkins.  I think have access to env variables in my stage 
stage('docker login'){
         steps {
          sh "docker login --username $dockerhub_USR --password $dockerhub_PSW"
         }
        }

Comment: In my case, I want something by which env variables stay specific to job & not global. I guess credentials will make them global.

Comment: I can't expose those environment variables, they should be stored encrypted or as a secret.

Comment: you can add them in `project parameters`. have a `file parameter` or `string parameters`. this will hide your env variables right.